# Using a class name stored in a property

Tags: php, syntax

I have a class name stored in an object property, and I would like to use it to access a static method from that class, but I can't seem to find a working syntax:

```
$this->className::staticMethod()
```

doesn't work and

```
{$this->className}::staticMethod()
```

doesnt' work either, does PHP have a correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
$class = $this->className;
$class::staticMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have PHP version > 5.2

```
call_user_func($this->className.'::staticMethod');
```

else

```
call_user_func(array($this->className, 'staticMethod'));
```

Also with arguments:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->className, 'staticMethod'), array($argument, $anotherArg));
```

Comment: Ok this works, but is quite ugly, I'd rather go through a temp variable if there is no better solution

Comment: OK first one is not too ugly

Comment: First one is not too bad, but it looks like a hack (which it is :)). It's the version with arguments that's ugly. +1 anyway for a working answer